# Reduce the space around in-line formulas in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

When inserting a formula into LibreOffice, there is a whole lot of padding between it and other words. How can I modify the formatting of formulas to make the padding much smaller?

LibreOffice 3.3.1

Comment: See Apache OpenOffice FAQ [How do I change the spacing around my formula?](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Formula/How_do_I_change_the_spacing_around_my_formula%3F).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LibreOffice applies a default `frame style` named `Formula` to formula objects. It has AutoSize activated by default, and also a default padding. It should be sufficient to modify that frame style.

To do so, open the stylist using <kbd>F11</kbd> and select the `Frame Styles`. It's the third button from left:

[image: select frame Styles]

Now, select the `Formula` style, right click and `Modify`:

[image: modify formula style]

Now, you can edit the details applying to every formula object in the current document, for example the space around the formula:

[image: edit style]

In addition, you could modify the formula object directly; under `Wrap` tab, it has some default spacing values.